# Curly braces in ng-repeat - Syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to filter a JSON list based on one of the contained values. For example, I have JSON objects where they all have name, type, description etc and I am attempting to filter based on the parameter stored in $stateParams (which happens to be type). It works if I hard code the type (e.g. "item in items| filter:{Type:'Grain'}").

Also, I know the value from $stateParams is working as I have it set to the page title. Is there a problem with my below syntax?

```
 <div class="list card">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{Type:'{{type}}'}">
      <a class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="onSelectItemList(item)">
        <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
        {{item.Name}}
      </a>
    <div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might not need the single quotes here ``'{{type}}'``. Just a thought.

Comment: <div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{Type:type}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#arguments) expects an [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), You should not interpolate (`{{`) the expression to value.

change

```
filter:{Type:'{{type}}'}
```

to

```
filter:{Type:type}
```

`type` is expression evaluated against scope and `{{type}}` --> Value of expression evaluated against the scope.

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{Type:type}">
```

You can't do nested interpolation. Filter is expecting an expression, therefore `type` is evaluated as is.